# Ethernet/8P8C crimp contacts bent

Tags: networking, ethernet

(if anyone knows correct terminology please correct).

Ive got a (fairly large) number of existing Ethernet cables that over the years many have got damaged connector clips, so got a crimp tool and some new connectors for them. However out of all 4 attempts I have tried, on crimping 2+ of the little copper contacts that bite into the wires have instead just bent to one side, and so gone between the gaps in in the crimp tool...

Unless this really is me doing something wrong (what?) I am inclined to blame the hardware, but is this the crimper or the new connectors I got? I tried to take a picture, as you can just about see looking from the left 3rd, 6th, 7th and 8th pins didn't get pushed in, and so don't form a connector. Unfortunately my camera was barely able to focus on it and then this website converted it to a JPEG...

Update: Connectors/Cable/Tools:
The wires are stranded (looks about 6 and no evidence of being aluminum/not copper), and the pins(?) have 2 little flat spikes lengthways along the cables (I understand to dig into it, while solid core connectors would have like 2 plates designed to go around the core?). Crimper was http://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/product/B0013EXTKK/ref=oh_aui_detailpage_o02_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1 (seemed to be highly rated, I already had tools for cutting/stripping).

Update2: Picture of crimp "prongs" (?)

Update3: Side picture of connector

Update4: Comparison with old connector.

[image: Picture of connector]
[image: Picture of crimp tool]
[image: Side picture of connector]
[image: Comparison with an old connector i did]
The top (used) connector is one from a few years back (different tool and connectors), the thing that concerns me that it might not be the tool I need to replace is just how thin the pins are on the new one that maybe a tool could legitimately bend some into a gap rather than pushing them in fully? In fact I can move individual pins to the sides significantly with my fingernail, is that normal?

Comment: What kind of crimping tool are you using?  I have never had a problem with the contacts bending to the side.  Most RJ45 crimping tools push the contacts in evenly.  Your picture is anything but.

Comment: Otherwise known as an RJ45, but 8P8C is the correct terminology for Ethernet cabling... & yes, when I first started I wasted more than I got right. Over the years the percentage just decreased - maybe it's just practise?

Comment: Is this a 3 piece end? I have seen the piece that goes at the tip of the wires and shoves all the way inside the connector installed wrong before, causing the prongs to not align when crimping. It's the piece that guides the pins in strait. This is only on the 3 piece style though I believe.

Comment: I added some info, the connector comes as a single part, possibly a mistake since getting all 8 wires in slots in the right order while not stripping the cable too far back proved harder than my experience with soldered connectors (3&5 pin XLR generally)...

Comment: It is stranded CAT5e UTP (which all seem to get gigabit link speeds fine so really not sure on the point of short CAT6 patch leads to start with). Looking closely seems in the rush/irritation of trying the 4th time I might have ended up with 2 wires being slightly short. But surely if anything if the wire is short enough for a pin to miss, it should be even more likely to get pushed in than if it actually had to go into the wire (in fact those ones that bent to the side don't appear to have even cut through the insulation)?

Comment: In regards to your secondary question, yes they do make RJ45 plugs specifically for stranded and solid cable.  Plugs for **stranded** have straight connectors and go through the middle of the wire strands.  Plugs for **solid** have Y-shaped connectors that split over each side of the wire.  In my experience, even if you use stranded plugs on solid wire, it doesn't result in the problem you're describing.

Comment: Pretty sure its stranded connector, added another image.

Comment: When it comes to crimping, especially if you are going to be doing a lot of it, spend the extra money on a quality crimping tool.  Not only that, cheap, low quality RJ45 Network Modular Plug Connectors (the head) are often the biggest cause of crimping headaches.  Find a vendor with good reviews and your life will be much easier.

Answer (score 3):

The only time I've run into this was when using a crappy/loose/warn crimping tool, get/try a new and/or better one. There really should be no "gap" for them to slip in to.

Alternatively, I've had luck using said crappy crimper by figuring out which side they're slipping to, and then putting pressure on side of the connector in the opposite direction as they were slipping to while crimping, so that when you crimp, you're closing that gap they're sliding into. It's tricky to get down to a science, but it usually works.  If you have a LOT of ends to do, go get a new/better crimping tool. :)

[image: End in crimper - no gap...]

Also, ensure you're using the right cable ends.  There are ones for Solid-core wire, and ones for Stranded wire. If you're using the wrong ends for the cable type you have, you'll either have lots of problems crimping it properly, or you'll end up with crimp that fails in a few days/weeks/months.

[image: Stranded vs Solid core ends]

Comment: I added some info, surely there needs to be a bit of a gap since they get pushed in further than the plastic casing looking at my existing cables (although I'm also thinking from now comparing them that these "pins" are 3 or 4 times thinner than the old ones I cut off...).

Comment: There should be little to no gap around each of the crimper's teeth when within the plastic channel dividers on the cable connector. IE: the gap the metal blades are sliding into, shouldn't be there. :)

Comment: @FireLancer I added a picture of an end inside my (decent) crimper, showing a lack of gap for the blade to travel into between the crimping teeth and the channel sides.

Comment: How you get such a sharp picture... attempting to take one

Comment: I used my phone, and held the crimper in my other hand.  Took a few shots focusing on the crimp (my phone has he ability to focus in on what you touch on-screen), then used Gimp to crop it down to the important area of the picture. Just don't try and get too close; take a picture from further away in a high-res, and trim it down. Trust me, my first attempt was NOT clear. ;)

Comment: hehe now that I see the picture of the crimper you're using, that's almost exactly the same (ratcheted design, and blue) as the one we used to have that was also crimping badly, probably just coincidence, but still weird. :)  The one I've ben using these days is a no-name model similar in design to this one: http://www.amazon.co.uk/Crimping-Western-burnished-multi-component-Blister/dp/B000XUJQJS/

Comment: Added a picture. It seems to be similar with each prong being about as wide as the gap? Could it be on the connectors they made the things so thin it can slip between the plastic and tool?

Comment: They ARE pretty thin, so it doesn't take much of a gap. As I suggested, try it again, only put some pressure with your finger on the side of the connector while crimping it, pushing against it to close the gap on the side they're slipping to. If that works OK, then it's the probably a sloppy tool.

Comment: Managed a clear side image, its the 2nd variety of stranded connector you have there, the 2 teeth are just up against the insulation of the nearest pin, it didn't penetrate.

Comment: Added a comparison picture of the connector. Do you think those pins are fine and its just the crimper I need to replace?

Comment: I'd try new/different ends first, gotta be cheaper than a new crimper. :)

Answer (score 2):

I can see from the picture you provided that you're not cutting enough length on the individual wires before pushing the connector on.  In the middle of the picture, you can see the channels where the wires sit, but you cannot see the wires themselves.

You need to strip the cable a little bit farther and then push the wires all the way into the connector to where you can see the wires butting up against the front of the plug.  This will put pressure on the wires so that they cannot jiggle around when the pins bite into them when you crimp it down.

Take a look at Techie07's picture.  You can clearly see the ends of the wires fully extended into the channels in the connector.

Comment: yeah, noticed that i did that when remaking it again (my 1m cable is getting short...). Would it result in this though? I can try again but thinking 5th time wont be lucky...

Comment: There's no room in the channel for them to slip side to side, but if there's no pressure on them laterally, they can slip back and forth.  It's possible that when you crimp it down, the teeth push the wire end out of the way and bunch it up slightly rather than biting through it.

Comment: I managed to get a fairly clear side picture. The closest pin is one that bent to the side, the wire is clearly past the 2 little teeth at least?

Comment: It looks like you've got the pinout correct from what I can tell (looks like you're using type B). I think you might be right about the crimp tool. It's hard to see from the pics you have but the pins definitely look uneven. The side pic confirms; the pin is not fully clamped down to the wire. I also looked at the description of the crimper tool, and it does not specify if it's for Tyco/AMP or WES/SS cable ends.  The length of the cable head is different between the two.  Check out [this Wikipedia link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/8P8C#8P8C) under "Types and Incompatibility"

Comment: Going by the description pretty sure I am fine on the types since it seems to imply the spacing is different such it wouldn't fit at all (and they look the same as some of my old connectors that I had no issues with some years back)? Well you can just about see in the picture that some of the pins just pushed in, but others did not at all (I assume thats what you mean by uneven?), the end one in the side pic is such a pin, the reason I am not sure its (at least entirely) the crimp tool is the pins do look a lot thinner/flimsy than my old ones (added a side by side picture)